# Duplicate values to be removed on conditions

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables IAM and IAM_audit as below. I am trying to get results for account numbers who changed country or tax country. That works fine. However, I want the results to show only unique account numbers even though they are changed both in tax country and country. I don't want the account number 120 in this example to be shown twice? :) Is there a way.

Initial table Creation:

```
create table #Iam_audit1
(
     accnum int,
     invnumber int,
     audit_field varchar(10),
     field_before varchar(10),
     field_after varchar(10),
     modified_date datetime
)

insert into #Iam_audit1 (accnum, invnumber, audit_field, field_before,field_after, modified_date)
values 
       (120, 131, 'country', 'US', 'CAN','2014-08-09'),
      (120, 131, 'taxcountry', 'US','CAN', '2015-07-09'),
       (121, 132, 'country', 'CAN','US', '2014-09-15'),
       (121, 132, 'taxcountry', 'CAN', 'US','2015-09-14'),
       (122, 133, 'Taxcountry','CAN','US','2014-05-27')


create table #Iam
(
      Accnum int,
      invnumber int,
      country varchar(10) ,
      Taxcountry varchar(10)
)


insert into #Iam (Accnum, invnumber, country, taxcountry)
values (120, 131, 'CAN', 'CAN'), 
(120, 132, 'US', 'US'),
(122, 133, 'CAN', 'CAN')
```

Main QUERY:

```
  Select distinct IAMA.accnum,
       IAMA.invnumber,
IAM.taxcountry,
Iama.audit_field,
IAM.country
From #iam_audit1 IAMA
join #IAM iam on  iam.Accnum = iama.Accnum 
                                  AND iam.invnumber = iama.invnumber
Where Audit_Field IN ('TaxCountry', 'Country')
AND         (
         (isnull(Field_Before,'CAN') <> 'CAN' AND isnull(Field_After,'CAN') = 'CAN')
         OR (isnull(Field_Before,'CAN') = 'CAN' AND isnull(Field_After,'CAN') <> 'CAN')
        )
```

The current Results

```
accnum  invnumber   taxcountry  audit_field country
120     131            CAN        country        CAN
120     131            CAN        taxcountry    CAN
122     133            CAN        Taxcountry    CAN
```

Expected Results:

```
   accnum   invnumber   taxcountry  audit_field country
    120     131            CAN        country        CAN
    122     133            CAN        Taxcountry    CAN
```

Comment: The issue is that audit_field is part of the data set, so those 2 rows with accnum 120 are not duplicates. They are different. If 2 attributes changed, (country and taxcountry), why emit 'country' as the audit_field in the desired result? What criteria determines which audit_field is retained as the one to keep?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `audit_field` is in the select clause you will have duplicates. After refactoring the original query you can see that it is the only field with the potential to cause duplicates if your `#IAM` table has unique account numbers i.e.  `accnum`. This is because all of the other columns in the select clause can be from the `#IAM` table.

```
select distinct
      IAM.accnum
    , IAM.invnumber
    , IAM.taxcountry
    , IAMA.audit_field -- causing the 'duplicates' you describe
    , IAM.country
from
    #iam_audit1 IAMA
join
    #IAM IAM
    on 
        IAM.Accnum = IAMA.Accnum 
        and
        IAM.invnumber = IAMA.invnumber
where
    IAMA.Audit_Field IN ('TaxCountry', 'Country')
    and (
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') <> 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') = 'CAN')
            or
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') = 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') <> 'CAN')
        )
```

Depending on your specific use requirements (and version of SQL Server) there are a few different workarounds you could try if you really don't want multiple records for a single account number.

First, you could just remove the `audit_field` from the select clause.

```
select distinct
      IAM.accnum
    , IAM.invnumber
    , IAM.taxcountry
    , IAM.country
from
    #iam_audit1 IAMA
join
    #IAM IAM
    on 
        IAM.Accnum = IAMA.Accnum 
        and
        IAM.invnumber = IAMA.invnumber
where
    IAMA.Audit_Field IN ('TaxCountry', 'Country')
    and (
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') <> 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') = 'CAN')
            or
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') = 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') <> 'CAN')
        )
```

which produces

```
accnum  invnumber   taxcountry  country
120     131         CAN         CAN
122     133         CAN         CAN
```

Second, you could get the account number and the number of different audit_fields that changed.

```
select distinct
      IAM.accnum
    , IAM.invnumber
    , IAM.taxcountry
    , count(distinct IAMA.audit_field) as cnt_audits_with_changes
    , IAM.country
from
    #iam_audit1 IAMA
join
    #IAM IAM
    on 
        IAM.Accnum = IAMA.Accnum 
        and
        IAM.invnumber = IAMA.invnumber
where
    IAMA.Audit_Field IN ('TaxCountry', 'Country')
    and (
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') <> 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') = 'CAN')
            or
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') = 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') <> 'CAN')
        )
group by
      IAM.accnum
    , IAM.invnumber
    , IAM.taxcountry
    , IAM.country
```

which produces

```
accnum  invnumber   taxcountry  cnt_audits_with_changes country
120     131         CAN         2                       CAN
122     133         CAN         1                       CAN
```

Third, if you are using SQL Server 2017 or later you can use the [string aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to concatenate the `audit_fields`

```
select distinct
      IAM.accnum
    , IAM.invnumber
    , IAM.taxcountry
    , string_agg(IAMA.audit_field, ', ') as list_audits_with_changes
    , IAM.country
from
    #iam_audit1 IAMA
join
    #IAM IAM
    on 
        IAM.Accnum = IAMA.Accnum 
        and
        IAM.invnumber = IAMA.invnumber
where
    IAMA.Audit_Field IN ('TaxCountry', 'Country')
    and (
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') <> 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') = 'CAN')
            or
            (isnull(IAMA.Field_Before,'CAN') = 'CAN' and isnull(IAMA.Field_After,'CAN') <> 'CAN')
        )
group by
      IAM.accnum
    , IAM.invnumber
    , IAM.taxcountry
    , IAM.country
```

which produces

```
accnum  invnumber   taxcountry  list_audits_with_changes    country
120     131         CAN         country, taxcountry         CAN
122     133         CAN         taxcountry                  CAN
```